# expect_not_equal in pkg:testthat

Tags: r

I want to test that two values are *not* equal using 'testthat'.  I can test equality using something like

```
expect_that(x, equals(y))
```

But, what if I expect them to not be equal?  I could use

```
expect_false(x == y)
```

Is this the right way to do it or is there something like

```
expect_that(x, not_equals(y))
```

Answer (score 16):

The function `testthat::equals()` is really a wrapper around `all.equal`.  So you can construct your test like this:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 2:6
expect_false(isTRUE(all.equal(x, y)))
expect_false(isTRUE(all.equal(x+1, y)))
Error: isTRUE(all.equal(x + 1, y)) isn't false
```

You need to use `isTRUE` in there, since `all.equal` returns a character string if its arguments aren't equal.